# AngularJS: filter by inner array object field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following data:

```
organizations:[{
                name: "foo",
                contacts: [{
                             firstName = "John",
                             lastName = "Doe",
                             email = "john.doe@email.com"
                          },...]
               },...]
```

Then I have a table where I list all the organizations and I want to know if it is possible to filter the rows in the table according to a firstName filter or a email filter.

For example I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="name" ng-model="search.name">

<tr ng-repeat="organization in organizations | filter:search">
    <td>{{organization.name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.contacts[0].firstName}} {{ client.contacts[0].lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{client.contacts[0].email}}</td>
</tr>
```

It works filtering only by the 'name' field. I tried something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="search.contacts">
```

But it searches in all fields of the objects in the contacts array, but I want to specifically search by firstName. How can I do?

Comment: did u try  <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="search.contacts.firstName">

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work I think because contacts is an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a filter function like `filter:filterBy`.

Example (relies on underscore.js):

```
scope.filterBy = function(row) {
    return !!_.where(row.contacts, {firstName:scope.search.name}).length;
}
```

Comment: One thing to note about filters is that they need to be fast. If for any reason you see that filters are slowing you down try $watch-ing the filter properties then manually filtering your array and in the template ng-repeat over the filtered array

Comment: Indeed @LiviuT. For a small number of rows, a filter should be fine.